# Como inserir um datetime de meia-noite no mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, datetime

Estou usando o ***Framework Laravel 5.8***, estou tentando cadastrar um registro no banco de dados onde eu preciso setar na `API` algumas datas.

Embora elas sejam `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, eu preciso também poder inserir um registro definido por parâmetro através desta `API` (nesta tabela, eu tenho 4 campos de data: `start, end, updated, created`):

Aqui começa o problema:

O problema só acontece quando a data é meia-noite, ou seja: `00:00:00`

Primeiro tentei inserir no formato americano mesmo, e deu o seguinte erro:

> "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2018-11-04 00:10:10' for column 'end' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `Schools` (`scb_code`, `owner_id`, `name`, `cnpj`, `zipcode`, `neighborhood`, `city`, `state`, `phone`, `site`, `number`, `plan`, `start`, `end`, `access`, `address`, `guten_version`, `type`, `domain`, `scn_id`) values (1, 2, Escola teste, 123, 123, Jardim Paulista, São Paulo, SP, (11) 123-123, http://www.xxx.com.br, 123, 14, 2018-05-04 15:46:39, 2018-11-04 00:10:10, ?, Al. xyz, ?, 1, ?, ?))"

Então criei um método para que a data convertesse para o formato `timestamp` já que é um `timestamp` o campo do banco, acreditei que resolveria o problema, mas, não resolveu

Método fail:

```
public static function setFormatDateTimeToTimestamp($data, 
                                                    $fields = ['start', 
                                                               'end',
                                                               'created', 
                                                               'updated']
)
{
    if (count($fields)) 
    {
        foreach($fields as $field) 
        {
            if (isset($data[$field]) && 
                $data[$field] != null && 
                strrpos($data[$field], " 00:") !== false) 
            {

                $dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data[$field]);
                if ($dt) 
                {
                   $data[$field] = $dt->getTimestamp();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Deu na mesma, só que diferente, o erro ainda persiste:

> "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1541290210' for column 'end' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `Schools` (`scb_code`, `owner_id`, `name`, `cnpj`, `zipcode`, `neighborhood`, `city`, `state`, `phone`, `site`, `number`, `plan`, `start`, `end`, `access`, `address`, `guten_version`, `type`, `domain`, `scn_id`) values (1, 2, Escola teste, 123, 123, Jardim Paulista, São Paulo, SP, (11) 123-123, http://www.xxx.com.br, 123, 14, 2018-05-04 15:46:39, 123, ?, Al. Santos, ?, 1, ?, ?))"

**A tabela está neste formato:**

```
CREATE TABLE `Schools` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `scb_code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `scb_code_owner` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cnpj` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `neighborhood` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `site` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(14) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `plan` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `start` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `end` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `access` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `guten_version` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `domain` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `scn_id` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disable_block_content_teacher` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `external_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_Schools_schools_base1_idx` (`scb_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1589 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Agora eu não entendo porque através do Mysql Workbench numa versão mais recente eu consigo inserir o raio da data no formato que eu quero usando um simples `INSERT`, porém quando estou usando o Framework do Laravel, estou com esse problema, que na verdade parece ser um problema do `MySQL` e não do `Laravel`, ou é o `Laravel` que está me sabotando no `MySQL`, alguém sabe o que está acontecendo aqui?

Essa [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) pode talvez responder o problema, porém ainda não estou entendo o que tem de errado. E isso só acontece quando o mês é 11.

Comment: Meu chute é que seja por causa do horário de verão. O PHP e/ou o MySQL deve estar configurado com um timezone do Brasil, e no dia 04/11/2018, à meia-noite, os relógios foram adiantados em uma hora, então todos os minutos entre 00:00 e 00:59 são pulados e não existem neste timezone. Por isso 00:10:10 é uma data inválida para este timezone. O jeito é mudar o timezone, **ou** mudar para um horário válido (01:10:10, por exemplo) - ah sim, o timezone tb pode ser mudado **por conexão** (além do PHP e do MySQL terem suas próprias configs)

Comment: Faça o teste com "2017-10-15 00:10:10" (também é um dia que houve mudança de horário de verão), se der o mesmo erro provavelmente é por causa do timezone do Brasil mesmo. Veja [esse teste](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88ed2c/1), se remover o `set time_zone` funciona (pois o SQL Fiddle está configurado com UTC)

Comment: Mas o horário de verão não começa em outubro?

Comment: Em 2018 foi mudado para novembro: [notícia](https://g1.globo.com/politica/eleicoes/2018/noticia/2018/10/01/horario-de-verao-de-2018-so-comeca-depois-das-eleicoes.ghtml) - [wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_per%C3%ADodos_em_que_vigorou_o_hor%C3%A1rio_de_ver%C3%A3o_no_Brasil) - [decreto](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2015-2018/2017/decreto/D9242.htm)

Comment: Tudo muito estranho, você relata: `O problema só acontece quando a data é meia-noite, ou seja: 00:00:00` e no erro a data está `2018-11-04 00:10:10` ou seja, já é uma informação estranha de relato de erros. Eu acabei fazendo o teste e não deu erro algum essa data, faltou você colocar o seu `model` na pergunta e como esse dado está vindo realmente, tem como colocar? O timezone influencia em outros aspectos, mas, nesse não, porque a reclamação é do formato tem que ver configurações desse banco de dados

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Eu fiz testes forçando o timezone com `set time_zone='America/Sao_Paulo'` e o erro ocorre. Ao usar outro timezone (como UTC, ou outro que não tenha horário de verão nesta data), o erro não acontece. O que pode acontecer é que as informações de timezones não estejam atualizadas no seu caso (ele ainda pode estar com a regra antiga, pois em 2017 o horário de verão começa em outubro, e somente em 2018 foi mudado para novembro, mas o MySQL acho que não se atualiza automaticamente - teste com '2018-10-21 00:10:10' só pra ver se é isso mesmo). Ou vc está usando outro timezone mesmo...

Comment: @hkotsubo eu fiz os dois testes ... tanto o meu local quanto UTC, fiz vários teste e não deu erro algum, na minha experiência é o MYSQL, mas, não tenho como confirmar!

Comment: @hkotsubo `>>> App\TimesOf::create(['description' => 'Time 3', 'created' => '2018-10-21 00:10:10']);
=> App\TimesOf {#753
     description: "Time 3",
     created: "2018-10-21 00:10:10",
     id: 5,
   }` roda que é uma beleza ... eu acho que é o banco de dados, esses dias tive um problema com SQLServer (ele grava no formato brasileiro e enviar a informação no formato norte americano, ou seja, um erro grave de configuração do servidor)

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Na verdade eu testei direto no MySQL, mas de qualquer forma o problema deve estar em alguma config mesmo (ou no banco, ou na conexão)

Comment: Eu testei em outra máquina aqui com um MySQL mais recente e parou de dar problema, deve ser alguma configuração da versão do meu MySQL: 5.7.25. Eu nem vou esquentar com isso mais até porque o MySQL em produção é mais recente.

Answer (score 1):

O problema das datas e bem comun. O problema vem geralmente do fato que o servidor não esta no seu pais.
A solução mas fácil e colocar no inicio de cada pagina:

```
// Para todas as datas
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
// Para triagem e todas as funçoes de "string"
$ret = setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR.utf-8");
```

Depois disso, precisa pensar so "sou no Brasil" e parar usar um formato do EUA.

O outro ponto vem do tipo que vc escolhe para os campos:

- "end" é do tipo timestamp. E "2018-11-04 00:10:10" não é um Time Stamp.
- Tantar inserir "2018-11-04 00:10:10" num campo tipo "date" vai inserir "2018-11-04"
- Tantar inserir "2018-11-04 00:10:10" num campo tipo "datetime" vai inserir "2018-11-04 00:10:10"
- Tantar inserir "2018-11-04 00:10:10" num campo tipo "timestamp" vai dar error.

Ou você muda o tipo do seu campo, ou transforma a data em `TimeStamp` usando `mktime()`.

*So para colocar um info a mais: se vc tenta gravar "2018-11-04 00:00:00" num campos tipo "date" ou num campo tipo "datetime" os dois casos vão dar o mesmo resultado, porque "2018-11-04 00:00:00 = 2018-11-04". A diferencia vai ser visível só com valor tipo "2018-11-04 00:10:10" por que "2018-11-04 00:10:10 != 2018-11-04". Isso pode explicar a confusão.*

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido. A versão MySQL 5.7.x não está com o timezone incorreto do Brasil, correção:

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+3:00';
QUIT
```

Comment: Mas ai que eu discordo, timezone no banco deveria ser sempre em GMT/"utc" e a aplicação que usa o banco deveria compensar o horário, afinal de contas se tiver um horário de verão (Daylight Saving Time) em um estado brasileiro as coisas vão se conflitar, eu entendo que pode ser uma aplicação simples e que isso resolve para você no momento, mas acredite, isso é acumular problemas para o futuro. Me parece que o teu banco estava correto, e salvando corretamente [...]

Comment: [...]  o que estava ERRADO é o teu app laravel, que deveria saber que baixou em UTC e deveria aplicar a timezone do Brasil (do seu estado) no momento de ler a info do banco, podendo fazer diretamente na query ou no parse da string que contém a data.